# matplotlib_venn left top heading does not fit

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-venn

The following code cut the legend of the right top circle.

[image]

Is there a way to move the legend?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib_venn import venn3_unweighted

plt.style.use('seaborn')

plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
#plt.title("Venn Diagram For Three Random Sets")
#Nsyl (33,773 genes)
# (Set1,Set2,1n2,Set3,1n3,2n3,1n2n3)
venn3_unweighted(subsets=(703, 659, 5205, 3444, 1583, 1580, 17280),
      set_labels=('Nlab (45,309 genes)', 'Nqld (49,639 genes)', 'Ngla (53,626 genes)'))

plt.show()
```

Comment: Have you tried just increasing your figsize a bit?  Maybe `plt.figure(figsize=(5.5, 5.5))`?  Otherwise, the call to `venn3_unweighted` returns a VennDiagram object (https://github.com/konstantint/matplotlib-venn/blob/master/matplotlib_venn/_common.py).  That object has a few methods including one to get the label by id.  It's unclear what kind of matplotlib object that label is, but once you have it you may be able to manipulate directly.

Comment: `plt.figure(figsize=(5.5, 5.5))` helped, but the venn diagram is not centered.

Comment: If it were me, I'd just create my own venn diagram in matplotlib (about 13-lines of code to recreate that figure) and then I'd have full control over everything.  That package (matplotlib_venn) isn't well documented (so I'd stay away from it).

Comment: The other option (which would be easy) would be to leave off those labels in the call to venn3_unweighted and then just add them yourself with matplotlib.text ... or maybe change the strings so that they are shorter, or contain a new line: `"Nlab\n(45,309 genes)"` for example.

Comment: @TravisJ `Nlab\n(45,309 genes)` helped but how would your own Venn diagram in matplotlib look?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the layout of the figure to tight?

```
plt.tight_layout()
```

It will not really move the label text, but it should make sure to not cut it off.

Comment: `plt.tight_layout()` did not help.